# Is this way of checking if point B is "behind" point A correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's work in the 2D Cartesian plane.

- I have a set of points, each with an orientation.
- As I am working with maps, the orientation angle $\delta$ is $0$ if aligned with the y axis, and increases clockwise, so $\delta = \pi/2 - \theta$ would be the transformation from a traditional trigonometric angle $\theta$.

Let's take point A $(x_a, y_a)$ with orientation $\delta_a$, and point B $(x_b, y_b)$ of which we do not need the orientation.

I am dividing the plane in 2 halves.
The delimiting line goes through A and is perpendicular to the given orientation.
The "positive" half is the one where a point would end if we start on the line and we move in the direction of the given orientation.
The other half plane is "negative".

I am trying to find out if point B is in the "negative" half by checking:

$$x_a \cdot sin(\delta_a) + y_a \cdot cos(\delta_a) > x_b \cdot sin(\delta_a) + y_b \cdot cos(\delta_a) $$

Is this correct?

I am asking because I thought it was, but I am not getting the expected result with a test I am running now.

Comment: (1) You should include a Diagram. (2) You can compute the "regular" orientation & transform to "new" orientation & compare. (3) You can use complex numbers (or vectors) to make it a Standard Case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the orientation unit vector is $n = (\cos \delta_a, \sin \delta_a) $, then the equation of the "positive" half plane is

$ (r - A) \cdot n \gt 0 $

where $ r = [x, y]^T $ and $ A = [x_a, y_a]^T $

So, if $B = [x_b, y_b] $ is the "negative" half plane, in other words, it is "behind" point A, then it must satisfy

$ (B - A) \cdot n \lt 0 $

i.e.

$ x_a \cos \delta_a + y_a \sin \delta_a \gt x_b \cos \delta_a + y_b \sin \delta_a $

Hence, your inequality that you have in your question is correct.

Comment: @Prem I don't see the need for a diagram, when Nathalie has perfectly understood and answered the question.

Comment: No Problem , that is your choice. You said you were encountering some "error" , which remains unresolved & will remain unresolved even with this Answer. My thinking is that wrong "Interpretation/assumption" leads to wrong conclusion while "clarity" leads to resolution. @Federico

Comment: @Prem don't go around presuming stuff. don't presume the error won't be solved (or isn't solved already) just because this question did not find it. and don't presume finding the error would be on topic here, please.

Comment: I am not presuming stuff , it is common to say "A Picture is worth a thousand words" , You may have already found the Solution or you will eventually find the Solution , but this "Question & Answer" is not the Solution to your Problem. I have come across many cases where two folks thought that they were talking about the same thing but when Drawn on black board , they then realised their Different Interpretations/Assumptions. That is my last comment on this topic , @Federico , I will be deleting all my comments a while later. Wishing you all the best !